# Getting warning while validating app from organizer in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am having an app which is ready to upload on appStore.

I have successfully created my profiles and now trying to validate my app through xCode.

But As my apps are transferred from another developer account. It gives me error like shown in the below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

There is not Entitlement.plist file in my project anywhere.

This is the newer version of my app so I can't change the bundle Id also.

How can I solve this issue?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the AppId is different (the first part) in the current bundle, ideally it should get transferred to your developer account when the app is transferred. Check on that first and also ,

1. Make Sure you signing with the correct provision file from your developer account.
2. On the iTunes Connect developer guide says ,

> To maintain a great user experience within the app, make sure the
>   recipient is informed about any special functionality such as keychain
>   details or push notifications. In this way, that functionality will be
>   maintained in the app for future updates. App IDs are transferred
>   automatically in the Provisioning Portal.

and also

> After an app is transferred, its associated App ID is also transferred
>   to the recipient’s Member Center account. If the transferor’s App ID
>   was a wildcard App ID, it’s converted to an explicit App ID that
>   exactly matches the app’s bundle ID. Associated client SSL
>   certificates for push notifications aren’t transferred. If the app
>   uses Apple Push Notifications service (APNs), the recipient needs to
>   create a client SSL certificate using Member Center to reenable it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created a new profile for distribution from my developer's account. I created a new certificate for distribution also. The AppId is was already created with the bundle id which is same from my iTunes Account so i took that.

Comment: "After an app is transferred, its associated App ID is also transferred to the recipient’s Member Center account" , so shouldn't you use that to create the new provision ? I haven't done this before, guessing.

Comment: So the app id remains same or not when you transfer your app from another developer's account?

Comment: Yes, I took that same AppId to create my provisioning profile.Still it gives me error like this.

Comment: How did you get rid of this problem. I'm stuck in this right now. Please help. :( @Manthan

Comment: @Tulon:I actually submitted the app with this warnings. Some things are weird from apple some times. Sometimes it gives the errors and sometimes not. So try to submit with the warnings. Not sure but it should work fine.